# Why repeat a try statement in AppleScript before returning an error?

Tags: applescript, photos

I’m trying to learn AppleScript and have seen the following example for the Photos app:

```
try
    set thisId to id of item 1 of sel
on error errText number errNum
    display dialog "Error: cannot get the image ID" & errNum & return & errText & "Trying again"

    try
        delay 2
        set thisId to id of item 1 of sel
    on error errTexttwo number errNumtwo
        display dialog "Skipping image due to repeated error: " & errNumtwo & return & errTexttwo
        error "giving up"
        return
    end try --second attempt
end try
```

Why is there a second `try` statement doing the same thing after a short delay before giving up? The same is done in several places in this example script.

Is this a normal way of handling errors in AppleScript or is this specific for Photos and if so why?

Comment: The example script was found here: https://discussions.apple.com/docs/DOC-250000436

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applescript is seems to suffer with timing issues that usually are solved be using a delay. Often this delay needs to be tuned to match the speed of a particular model Mac. In other words, the delay hard coded in the the AppleScript may work on a newer faster Mac, but need to be increased when run on a slower Mac.

Comment: Do I understand you correct that there is a possibility that an error found in the “outer” try is caused by a timing issue and to take care of this situation you try to do the same ting once again. And that this is something specific for AppleScript - meaning one cannot trust the execution of a script, because to my understanding the statements inside the try are AppleScript internal and has nothing to do with any kind of interaction with Photos.

Comment: You are correct. **One cannot trust the execution of a script.** I suppose when a delay is necessary, one should use a delay of at least a hour. Only, then can one trust the execution of the script.